# SDL Web 8.5: Access to the path denied when adding a Custom Page

Tags: web8, gui-extensions, web8.5, custom-page

I try to create a new Custom Page and got below error. Steps mentioned below for replicating the issue.

> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>          at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>          at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
>          at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.CME.General.SaveCustomPages(XmlReader reader)
>          at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.CME.General.SaveNewCustomPage(String xml)
>          at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.CME.General.SaveNewCustomPage(String xml, Boolean doneEditing)
>          at SyncInvokeSaveNewCustomPage(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>          at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)

**Procedure**

1. Open Content Manager Explorer.
2. In the Shortcuts Navigation pane, select the Custom Pages node.
3. Open the Ribbon Toolbar **Create** tab and click **New Custom Page**.  The New Custom Page window opens.
4. Fill in or modify the following fields:

   - `Name` - the name of the Custom Page.
   - `URL` - the URL of the Page.
   - `Default` - (optional) select if you want to set this Page as the splash screen for all Users that access the Content Manager.
5. Click Save and Close.
6. Access to the path `D:\tridion\web\WebUI\Editors\CME\Preferences\CustomPages.xml` is denied.

[image]

Looking for solution and suggestion to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check file permission on the `Preference` folder and `custompages.xml`

Ensure **Network Service** account has read/write to `Preference` folder and full control on `custompages.xml`